# I'm making a video call application using the Zegocloud sdk, but an error occurs when I run it

Tags: flutter, videocall, zegocloud

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform express-video-3.0.2.aar (com.github.zegolibrary:express-video:3.0.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find express-video-3.0.2.aar (com.github.zegolibrary:express-video:3.0.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jitpack.io/com/github/zegolibrary/express-video/3.0.2/express-video-3.0.2.aar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

there are no errors but when I

Comment: Found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade the SDK version